# How to loop vertically through a 2d array in java

Tags: java

Supposedly i want to loop through the 2d array vertically for example given a 2*2 array

- **a[0]**   a[0] 
   **a[1]**   a[0] 
   **a[2]**   a[0]

How do i output the values accordingly to the bold part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(a[i][0]);
}
```

Of course, you can replace the `0` with any in-bounds column.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to loop through the array vertically by changing the first dimension, you need to have the variable in the inner for loop to be the first dimension like the code below:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
             for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                 System.out.println(a[j][i]);
             }
         }
```